# Reverse a string algorithm - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, function, reverse

I'm trying to solve this algorithm but am getting undefined at the beginning. Can anybody explain why this is happening so I may solve it?

// Given a String S, reverse the string without reversing its individual words. Words are separated by dots.

```
function reverseStr(str){
    newStr="";
    for(var i=str.length;i>=0;i--){
        newStr+=str[i];
    }
    console.log(newStr);
}

reverseStr("hcum.yrev.margorp.siht.ekil.i");
```

Output: undefinedi.like.this.program.very.much

Comment: Check `str[str.length]`

Comment: `var i = str.length - 1`

Comment: function reverseStr(str){
    newStr="";
    for(var i=str.length;i>0;i--){
        newStr+=str[i-1];
    }
    console.log(newStr);
}

reverseStr("hcum.yrev.margorp.siht.ekil.i");

Comment: And your code doesn't fulfi the requirements of reversing the string without reversing the words. From that assignment I'd expect `reverse("you.are.how")` to return "how.are.you"

Comment: Ah yes, you were all right. Thank you

Comment: @JeromeTaylor wouldn't it be more sensible to start and end the loop at the correct index instead of manipulating the current index in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @derpirscher You are right. Looks like I'm going to have to spend more time on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are indexed starting from 0, so the last index is 1 less than the string's length. That means you should do `var i=str.length-1` instead of `var i=str.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
function reverseString(str) {
    Let newString = "";
    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        newString += str[i];
    }
    return newString; // "olleh"
}
 
reverseString('hello');
```